# how to set vertical space constraint in Auto layout with baseline?

Tags: ios, ios7, autolayout, xcode5

there are two labels in view. my designer will offer me markman as following

[image]

However, I can only set the constraint in Xcode like following

[image]

I mean, the designer need me to align the two labels with baseline, however, I can set the space of two labels with frame. Is there a way to set space of two labels with baseline instead of label's frame using Autolayout?

Answer (score 2):

thanks @Arkadiusz, @Fogmeister, I have implemented a `NSLayoutConstraint` category to do it.

```
@implementation NSLayoutConstraint (MarkmanSpace)
- (void)updateSpaceBetweenTopView:(UIView *)topView bottomView:(UIView *)bottomView {
    UIFont *topViewFont = [self fontFromView:topView];
    UIFont *bottomViewFont = [self fontFromView:bottomView];
    if(topViewFont && bottomViewFont) {
        CGFloat padding = fabs(topViewFont.descender) + fabs([self lowercaseGlyphTopBaselineHeightForFont:bottomViewFont]);
        self.constant -= padding;
    }

}

- (UIFont *)fontFromView:(UIView *)view {
    UIFont *viewFont = nil;
    if([view isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) {
        viewFont = ((UILabel *)view).font;
    }
    return viewFont;
}

- (CGFloat)lowercaseGlyphTopBaselineHeightForFont:(UIFont *)font {
    return font.ascender - font.xHeight;
}

@end
```

but there's a problem ,which is the font.xHeight is lower the actual height for Chinese Character,

Answer (score 1):

Your designer wants you to use a baseline and an x-height, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baseline_(typography). A format option for the x-height isn't available in Auto Layout (see [NSLayoutFormatOptions](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSLayoutConstraint_Class/NSLayoutConstraint/NSLayoutConstraint.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010628-CH1-SW13)), so I don't think it's possible.

Comment: I haven't looked into it but I reckon there's a way to get the x-height from a UIFont. Then use the x-height as a metric adding the constraint (in code). Of course, it won't work with changing font sizes but you could poss update the constant or something...

Comment: @Fogmeister: That's right. You could set up a vertical spacing constraint between baselines of both labels and set its `constant` to the x-height. I was going to edit my answer, but you were faster with your comment :).